# Managing hierarchical security in Microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy

I am having a people hierarchy like below, where PersonA is the leader, PersonB, PersonC and PersonD are reports to PersonA
Same PersonB1 and PersonB2 reports to PersonB

```
PersonA
  PersonB     PersonC      PersonD
    PersonB1    PersonC1     PersonD2
    PersonB2
```

Now I have a table in teradata where confidential data is available for all the above persons.

Now I am looking for a solution in Microstrategy like below:
When PersonA will login he should be able to see his own and all others' data
When PersonB will login he should be able to see his own and his reportees' data (i.e. PersonB1 and PersonB2). He shouldn't be able to see other than PersonB, PersonB1 and PersonB2 data.
The same rule applies for other person in the hierarchy.

How this can be achieved in Microstrategy reporting tool

Comment: Do you already have access control in teradata that you wish to leverage (but not recreate) in MicroStrategy? Or are you looking to implement control in MicroStrategy that does not exist in teradata? If you don't already have the access restrictions in teradata - do you need restrictions over field values (users B and B1 can access data where field Region=Region1, and users B and B2 can access data where field Region=Region2)?  How do you define for each user what is considered "his own"?

Comment: Yes, I don't have control in Teradata to implement this and I want to implement to do it in Microstrategy. Yes, it is kind of field level restriction (as you have shown above) I want to implement here.